# Как узнать IP адрес устройства?

Tags: java, android

Сервер, на который я отправляю запрос определяет мой IP, а как получить этот IP программно, чтобы потом сравнить?

Comment: Учитывайте, что система может иметь одновременно несколько IP-адресов...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

И добавьте разрешения в манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

<sub>[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device-from-code).</sub>